# End-weight how I interpret

Tags: word-order

As you know, *I played soccer instead on Monday.* and *I played soccer on Monday instead.* mean the same.

if end-weight is applied, should I interpret reversely? For example, can *I played soccer twice on my birthday.* mean *I played soccer on my first birthday and I played soccer on my second birthday.* not twice on the same birthday?

In the end, should I interpret it in the same way as *I played soccer on my birthday twice*?

Another example,

1. I played soccer again on Monday.
2. I played soccer on Monday again.

They mean the same. I played soccer on the first Monday. And I played soccer on the second Monday

Comment: How many birthdays do you get in a year?

Comment: @JamesK One birthday.

Comment: @JamesK The gist is: Is it okay to indicate two different birthdays?

Comment: *I played soccer twice on my birthday.* would mean that you played soccer twice on the same day. If you are referring to two different years, the sentence must be explicit.

Comment: *I played soccer on my birthday, this year and the last year.*

Comment: @apaderno What about "I played soccer twice on my birthday, this year and the last year"?

Comment: @Faints I would say it is ambiguous.

Comment: "As you know"? To me,  _I played soccer instead on Monday_ means 'instead of doing something else that day', while _I played soccer on Monday instead_ means 'instead of playing on another day'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then, is "I played soccer instead on Monday" a special case?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes I thought like you before James K taught me end-weight.

Comment: Please add details IN your question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Another example doesn't come to my mind...

Comment: Details do not mean another example. It means sharing the research, explaining why you mention *end-weight* and maybe giving a definition of the linguistic term. This is a site for learners not for students studying linguistics. Details mean we do not have to infer from your question. By the number of questions posted and the number that have been downvoted by the community, I think you risk being question banned by the *system*. I would suggest spending time making your future questions interesting to as many users as possible and not just for yourself.

Comment: The 'end-weight principle' referred to by James is about _long structures_ (like the list of several subjects in 'The Little Prince'). _On Monday_ isn't long enough to need postponing to the end of the sentence.

Comment: Wait a moment. This account is only a day old. How come?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I deleted my account yesterday. But I renew the same account.

Comment: And did you delete account user182348 for a reason? Maybe the system *did* ban you from posting new questions?

Comment: @KateBunting I played soccer again on Monday. I found another example!

Comment: @Mari-LouA No I wasn't banned. Just delete for my kinda vacation. But I changed my mind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Think about it. If I was banned, I would change my account newly change my name.

Comment: Well, thinking about it, I wouldn't set up a new account only a day after I had deleted my old account.

Comment: Again, there is a slight difference in emphasis. _I **played soccer again** on Monday_ (having played on Saturday). _I **played soccer on Monday** again_ (having played last Monday).

Comment: @KateBunting What happened to "The grown-ups advised me to put away my drawings of boa constrictors, outside or inside, and apply myself instead to geography; history, arithmetic, and grammar."

Comment: Whadya mean, 'what happened to it?' James explained to you (and I mentioned above) that  his 'end-weight principle' does apply there.

Comment: Comments are not meant for extended discussion. If the question needs extra information, please use the "Edit" button to add it. To answerers, if extra information is needed, vote to close. If you have an answer, post it.

Comment: Faint's 2nd account self-deleted too…

Answer (score 2):

Both mean the same.  "I played twice on your birthday" is the same as "I played on my birthday twice".

I suppose the second *could* refer to two different birthdays. In context that is unlikely, since you only have one birthday a year.  "On my birthday" refers to just one day, not all your birthdays.
But:

> Matches are usually on Sunday, but this season we played twice on Saturday/ we played on Saturday twice, when the Sunday match had to be cancelled.

Comment: What about first one? could first one refer to two different birthdays?

Comment: The phrase "on my birthday" refers to just one birthday.

Comment: Is "I played soccer instead on Monday" a special case?

Comment: Although "Every year on my birthday I got to KFC" is valid for multiple birthdays, because it has the additional time qualifier "every year".

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning is created by context.**

If the emphasis there seems uncalled for, it's because I've said the same thing in at least 5 other questions in the past day.

Please understand: A sentence out of context can be ambiguous, vague, or even misleading. To present an out-of-context sentence and ask what it means can be a useful exercise for understanding how certain words or phrases work, but it can lead to the mistaken idea that certain words or phrases *always* mean a certain thing. If the out-of-context sentence would *usually* be taken a certain way, that might mean more about our assumptions than about language.

Now, first of all:

> "I played soccer instead on Monday" and "I played soccer on Monday instead" mean the same.

I would argue no, they don't. Again, context would probably clarify. But if there is no context, we are left to assume or invent one. And I would assume that the context of the first one is "I was supposed to play some other sport, but..." and the context of the second one is "I was supposed to play soccer on Tuesday, but..." While we could force each of them into the other usage, it would be a strange choice.

Meanwhile, if a stranger walks up to you, says "I played soccer on my birthday twice," and walks away, offering no further context, the *reasonable* and *most likely* assumption is that, on their most recent birthday, they played soccer two times. This has nothing to do with language or syntax, and everything to do with how we normally interpret these ideas. Without any further explanation, "on my birthday" typically suggests the closest occurrence of your birthday. If the past tense is used, we would think of the most recent one; if future, the next one.

Never rely on syntax alone to do the job of context. *Don't* walk up to strangers and blurt things. Use context to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences mean the same thing. And both are ambiguous. Either could mean, "I played twice on my birthday this year" or "I played on my birthday this year and I also played on my birthday last year." (Or some other combination of years, like, "I played on my birthday in 2023 and also on my birthday in 1997.") If you want to be clear which you mean you must add additional words.

Sometimes the reader could guess from context. Like if you said, "I competed in the national soccer tournament twice on my birthday", a reader would presumably assume you mean on your birthday in two different years, as I don't think they hold two national tournaments in the same year. But if you said, "I played soccer at the park with my friends twice on my birthday", either interpretation is possible. I'd probably guess twice on your most recent birthday, but that would just be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

One interpretation of your original quote

> I played soccer instead on Monday.
> I played soccer instead of cricket on Monday.

> I played soccer on Monday instead.
> I played soccer on Monday instead of Sunday.

You can apply a similar logic to 'again' as well as 'instead'.

However, you cannot apply the same rule to playing twice on your birthday; there is no real ambiguity & there is no obvious alternate meaning.
The chance of it meaning 'on two separate birthdays, I played soccer' is just too remote to be considered.

The differences can be subtle, but if you're careful in your writing, this is what these convey…

> I played soccer again on Monday. I had also played on Sunday.
> I played soccer on Monday again. Monday is the day I usually play soccer.

The most logical interpretation each time is that your 'instead' or 'again' refers back to the immediately preceding idea.